# ASP.NET MVC - Calling javascript function from another script does not work in view

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using ASP.NET MVC and I have a javascript file in `~Scripts/bundle/build.js`. The file is generated with webpack, which renders a bunch of ES6 javascript files in `Scripts`. I am loading `bundle.js` first and then calling the function in a different script like this:

```
// @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/Webpack")
<script src="~/Scripts/build/bundle.js"></script>
<script>
    connectToVnc();
</script>
```

(first line is commented, I have tried loading the script using bundles in `BundleConfig.cs`).

I get the error `connectToVnc is not defined`, even though it is defined in `bundle.js`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is your `bundle.js` script successfully loaded in the browser?  Check the browser's debugging tools to find out.

Comment: Does `connectToVnc` work in your console?

Comment: Webpack only loads the files as they are needed so although your function is in bundle.js, it may not have been loaded yet.  You should be placing the function call in the correct script that is loaded by webpack

Comment: @David I can locate the script in "Sources" (Chrome).

Comment: @aaron no, that does not work either.

Comment: @Pete I need to call a method from the `.cshtml` file to pass a variable from the server. Is there no way to call the function in `bundle.js`?

Comment: Could you not load the variable into an element in the dom as a data-attribute?  If not then the only way you could do it is to just put the function into a separate script and add it to the cshtml page manually

Comment: You can definitely call function from bundle.js. Check few things: 1) js path (scripts/build/bundle.js) is correct  2) check Network tab in chrome and if its loaded; check response tab to verify your function is in response; you have added function but browser renders old version from cache 3) As JS is case sensitive, verify the case of your function name.

Comment: @Shah all of that is correct. I see `bundle.js` both on the network and on the Sources in Chrome. The function is clearly and correctly defined in there. Are you sure about being able to call a function from `bundle.js`?

Comment: @Pete I will try sending the variable in data in html.

Comment: @A.Savva I'm just learning webpack myself so can't be more help but from what I have seen of it, I do a check for an element and if it exists, I require a script and that script usually does all the stuff I want for that element - for example, when I load an image carousel I'll do something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/uu1aga4t/

Comment: already replied - check answer from @frxstrem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43285725/unable-to-access-function-bundled-by-webpack)

Comment: try to run code in $(document).ready() block.